# Selecting environment in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am having configuration issue in Jenkins when running Selenium.

I have different environments setup in my Jenkins configuration but when I select the environment from drop down list in Jenkins it always runs in the environment added in the `main.properties` file.

Jenkins configuration:

[image: Jenkins configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin[image: ][1]]

specify the properties file and value.